# Как грамотно проверить в python 3 составлен ли ini файл коректно?

Tags: python-3.x, строки

Мне нужно зачитывать ini файлы на python 3.
В нем присутствуют строки типа [name]=[start]:[end]
Хочу проверить весьб файл на правильность составления файла, иначе выдам ошибку.

В голову приходит вариант проверить каждую строку на наличие "=" и следующим за ним ":".

```
for line in ini_file_content:
    index1 = line.index('=')
    index2 = line.index(':')
    # потом сравнения типа index1>index2 и подобные
```

Но программа неработает в том случае если один из знаков не присутствует вообще в строке. Мир python для меня достаточно новый и насколько я знаю он очень функционален. Если ли возможность решить этк проблему елегантно без большого количества кода?

Comment: В ini файлах ещё и секции есть: `[general]` И пустые строки. И комментарии

Comment: я уже очтсьтл от generalб пустых и коментариев.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего, попытаться распасить его. [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html):

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
list = config.read('cfg.ini')
if list:
  print(config['DEFAULT']['parameter'])
```

Comment: стоит явно упомянуть, что `configparser` требует наличия секции (в вашем примере `[DEFAULT]`). Стоит выключить лишние способности: `ConfigParser(interpolation=None, delimiters='=', empty_lines_in_values=False)` (чтобы если `=` отсутствует, то `:` как разделитель не срабатывало бы, так как оно в значении используется).